# Anonymous Recursive Pipes in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do anonymous recursion in R and also playing with pipes to learn. The code below works well

```
sorttt <- function(list){
  if (length(list) == 0) c() else c(max(list), Recall(list[list < max(list)]))
}

example %>% sorttt
```

But this code errors out with the error: `Error in example %>% function(list) { :  invalid formal argument list for "function"`

```
example %>% function(list){if (length(list) == 0) c() else c(max(list), Recall(list[list < max(list)]))}
```

Does anyone know why these two might act differently? These seem to be logically the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wrap anonymous functions in parentheses for them to work with pipes.

```
## doesn't work
1:10 %>% function(x) {mean(x)}
# Error in 1:10 %>% function(x) { : 
#   invalid formal argument list for "function"

## works with parens
1:10 %>% (function(x) {mean(x)})
# [1] 5.5
```

Same thing for your function:

```
1:3 %>% 
  (function(list){if (length(list) == 0) c() else c(max(list), Recall(list[list < max(list)]))})
# [1] 3 2 1
```

This is because `function` is itself a function. `A %>% function(x){...}` is interpreted as `function(A, x){...}`. The parentheses make sure the whole function definition is run before the pipe inserts an argument.